# Comparable matrix operations to multiplication for other basic operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Linear algebra newbie here with a quick question.

I know that in matrix multiplication, we multiply A, an n x d matrix with B, a d x m matrix, and we get an n x m matrix as our result.  I know typically matrix addition and subtraction are entrywise.

I would like to perform operations other than multiplication, but where every row in matrix A still interacts with every column in matrix B, as they do in matrix multiplication.  Do any of these operations exist as standard operations, and if so, what are they called?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Matrix multiplication over $\Bbb F_2$ can be seen as a version of matrix multiplication where multiplication is replaced with "and" and addition is replaced with "XOR".

Comment: It is also common to have a "multiplication" where we insert a matrix $C$ in between to go from $A$ and $B$ to $ACB$. Other than that, I don't know of any operations like the kind you're interested in.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, thanks for the response.  Is F2 a domain?  I'm not familiar with it.  The motivation for my asking was for an implimentation of the KNN algorithm, trying to calculate the distance between vectors.  I know it's built into SciKit, but I'm doing it myself to understand it better.  If there was a built in method that operated like matrix multiplication, but for subtraction, it would make this calculation very simple.  The other option is nested for loops, which are not as elegant (and slower).

Comment: $\Bbb F_2$ is just $\{0,1\}$ but with XOR instead of addition

Comment: It might help if you say exactly what the nested loops look like, and then maybe we can find a way to express the result elegantly with matrices